# Restcomm Failed to assign and create sbb object java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: restcomm

I try to use `Restcomm` with jdbc RA!
Someone can help me, I've errors when I try to do tests

```
2017-08-21 11:22:15,581 ERROR [org.mobicents.slee.runtime.sbbentity.SbbEntityImpl] (SLEE-EventRouterExecutor-1-thread-1) Failed to assign and create sbb object
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mobicents.slee.resource.jdbc.JdbcResourceAdaptorSbbInterfaceImpl cannot be cast to org.restcomm.slee.resource.jdbc.JdbcResourceAdaptorSbbInterface
    at sn.pmf.jdbc.jdbcSbb.setSbbContext(jdbcSbb.java:147)
    at org.mobicents.slee.runtime.sbb.SbbObjectImpl.<init>(SbbObjectImpl.java:124)
    at org.mobicents.slee.runtime.sbb.SbbObjectPoolFactory.makeObject(SbbObjectPoolFactory.java:146)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:974)
    at org.mobicents.slee.runtime.sbb.SbbObjectPoolImpl.borrowObject(SbbObjectPoolImpl.java:68)
    at org.mobicents.slee.runtime.sbbentity.SbbEntityImpl.assignSbbObject(SbbEntityImpl.java:744)
    at org.mobicents.slee.runtime.eventrouter.routingtask.EventRoutingTaskImpl.routeQueuedEvent(EventRoutingTaskImpl.java:362)
    at org.mobicents.slee.runtime.eventrouter.routingtask.EventRoutingTaskImpl.run(EventRoutingTaskImpl.java:128)
    at org.mobicents.slee.runtime.eventrouter.EventRouterExecutorImpl$EventRoutingTaskStatsCollector.run(EventRouterExecutorImpl.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The setSbbContext code part:

```
public void setSbbContext(SbbContext context) {
    this.tracer = context.getTracer("JdbcExampleSbb");
    this.contextExt = (SbbContextExt) context;
    this.jdbcRA =  (JdbcResourceAdaptorSbbInterface) this.contextExt
                  .getResourceAdaptorInterface(JdbcResourceAdaptorSbbInterface.RATYPE_ID, "JDBCRA");
    this.jdbcACIF = (JdbcActivityContextInterfaceFactory) this.contextExt
       .getActivityContextInterfaceFactory(JdbcActivityContextInterfaceFactory.RATYPE_ID);
}
```

Comment: Issue Resolved, Thanks a lot for your help :-)

Comment: Your welcome ;), next time consider the tagging of your post, with a single low-traffic tag like restcomm probably no one even saw your question. People who answers filter on tags to find questions to answer, hence correct tagging is critical to get good answers.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Resolved, Thanks a lot for your help :-) 
I just change the JDBC DU old release to 7.0.11